# What is 450 pips below spot for USD - JPY currency pair?

Tags: fx, pricing

I'm new to FX derivatives and I'm trying to price a derivative of USD - JPY pair at 450 pips below spot for USD - JPY. Let's assume that the spot is 109.36; would this mean that 450 pips below spot is 109.36 - 0.045 = 109.315?

If this is incorrect, please help me understand the intuition behind pips. I understand that 1 pip is 0.0001 of a movement in spot.

Comment: What specifically do you price? A [pip in JPY](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781119204831.app2#:~:text=A%20pip%20is%20the%20smallest,the%20counter%20or%20quote%20currency.&text=For%20the%20USDJPY%2C%20a%20movement,to%2080.01%20is%20one%20pip.) is usually 0.01. In options you would not say pips below spot - it is just a cost like you see [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/60516/54838).
450 JPY pips per EUR would be 4500 JPY if EUR notional is 1Mio. In forwards, usually you quote in points, not pips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most currency pairs, 1 pip is indeed 0.0001; however, because USD 1 $\approx$ JPY 100, in this context, 1 pip is larger, i.e. 0.01. So 450 pips is 4.5, and 109.36 - 4.5 = 104.86.

You may find this discussion [How is forex price precision (of the actual floating point number) determined?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/63782) useful.

Comment: Great, thanks. This is exactly what I've been looking for.

Now, in the case of USD - INR, how would you find what 450 pips represents? Since 1 USD is approx = 71 INR, the math for pips is not as straightforward as in USD - JPY where it is simply 0.01. 

Could you explain the intuition behind the calculation for finding which decimal place the pip will be in the USD - INR case?

Comment: Yes indeed USDINR pip is also 0.01. It is usually quite logical, but you should find your desk's lookup table.